# Warm transfers on Asterisk via the AMI

Tags: asterisk, pbx

Hi,

I'm busy developing a web interface for the asterisk PBX.

I'm looking for a way to initiate warm transfers via the web interface using the AMI.

I know that it's possible to initiate a warm transfer from the handset itself, but the requirement here is that it be done from the web interface.

I've done a fair amount of googling on the subject but I've not found anything thusfar.

Anybody know anything?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

> To see all of the available manager commands, use the "manager show
>   commands" CLI command.
>
> You can get more information about a manager command with the "manager
>   show command " CLI command in Asterisk.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/AMI+Manager+Commands

You also can consult this page(note, that you still have check on your asterisk version like described above)

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+API

You are probably asking about Redirect command to some special context with dialplan support.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of all the possible ways of getting info surrounding the AMI. I've explored all the data available and not yet found a solution.